# set width of characters with java

Tags: java, width, character

I was working on something and was wondering if there is any way to set width of a character.

For instance, lets say you enter character "i". I want to set the width of "i" to something (could be 1, 3, 6, etc inches or even pixels if that works). Once i is set, other letters will be get set (so A can be width of i times 3, C can be width of i times 2, etc etc). User only needs to input the width of i; all other characters will set themselves based on the width of i.

Pseudocode of what I want:

- Ask user for width of i
- User inputs 2 inches
- Width of i equates to 2
- A gets set to 6in, C gets set to 4in, etc etc --- this will be preset within the code
- User inputs a message
- Width of message is calculated
- Program outputs total calculated width of message

Is this possible? I have been trying to implement charsWidth. I would let user enter a message, message goes into an array, charsWidth would measure the array width, then finally output the width. The logic makes sense, but I am having rough time setting it up this way. Maybe there is a simpler way to implement this? This could be GUI-based, but I'm not familiar with GUI code so if it's text-based, it would be easier.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: This is not possible in console programming as far as I know. In a GUI, you have to play with the properties of JLabels, which is quite doable.

Comment: @ChrisChambers, he wants to explicitly set each character relative width. See *A **gets set** to 6in, C gets set to 4in, etc etc --- this will be preset within the code* and my answer.

Comment: I guess I'm a bit confused by the term "width." Is this the width of the character on screen?

Comment: Do you want to actually produce printed or displayed output using the widths, or just calculate the total width? BTW, there's a whole science, art and vocabulary around typesetting and character widths.  Characters are usually related to the _em-space_ which is nominally the width of the letter "M", and is the widest character in the font.  An _en-space_ is 1/2 the width of an em.

Comment: I guess it's OP's own *property* of a letter here, not related to screen/print.

Comment: You're are talking about calculating the width of the message. How are you actually going to **output** the message?

Comment: @PM77-1, he hasn't written anything about outputting it. He just wants to output the width. Read the code block again (should be a list).

Comment: It will output in regular text, of course. I don't want actual message to be 20 feet wide with letter i taking up up the entire screen lol. I just want it to represent 20feet. Actual visual text within Eclipse console might be regular size

Comment: @harshm0de, see my answer, you'll get just what you need.

Comment: @Michał Rus - You seem to be right. Upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `HashMap` to assign an i-relative width to every letter. Then, as you get the message, iterate over every letter, and accumulate values for the consecutive letters from the `HashMap`.

Example:

```
Map<Character,Double> map = new HashMap<Character,Double>();
map.put('a', 3.0);
map.put('b', 2.1);
// ... and so on

String msg = ... // get the message
Double width = 0.0;

for (Character c : msg.toCharArray())
    width += map.get(c);
```

Comment: You are not answering the question about setting the width of characters in java. It's more a comment than an answer ;)

Comment: @PM77-1, *"Program outputs total calculated width of message"*? :-)

Comment: @TheEwook, look again at his requirement set, especially *"A gets set to 6in, C gets set to 4in, etc etc --- this will be preset within the code"*.

Comment: @MichałRus `Map<Char,Double> map = new HashMap<Char,Int>();` `Int` doesn't exist in java. It's `Integer` or `int`. One more thing, there is a problem in your map declaration (Double in the Map side and Int in the HashMap side). Is it really necessary to use a Double?

Comment: @TheEwook, thanks, edited 2 mins ago, hit refresh. :) I think Double is a better choice... If 'W' is 2.0 times wider than 'i', how wide is 'F'?

Comment: This definitely makes sense, as does other responses. I will try to implement this first though. It looks fairly simple logically. Will let you know if I run into any issues

Comment: @harshm0de, and be sure to accept the answer. :-)

Comment: "The method add(String, double) is undefined for the type Map<Character,Double>" - any ideas on that? Won't let me add to the map. I tried doing just Map<Char,Double> but it says Char cannot resolve to a type.

Comment: @harshm0de, ahhh, sorry! I've edited the answer. Use `Character` and single quote, `'`.

Comment: @MichalRus - Are you sure add() would work with hashmap? The one error I keep getting is with map.add(). Says "The method add(char, double) is undefined for the type Map<Character,Double>". I'm thinking maybe the two are incompatible with each other? I don't know what else I could be doing wrong man.

Comment: @harshm0de, use `put()` instead of `add()`, corrected, thanks. I was writing from memory... sorry. :<

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way is to have a method that returns the multiple of the letter using switch cases. 
so

```
public int multiple(char letter)
{
 switch(letter){
 case 'a': 
   return 2;
 case 'b':
   return 3;
...
...

}
}
```

then read in the string using a scanner,
iterate through the string and add to a running count.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String message = scan.nextLine();
int width;
for(int i=0,i<message.length(),i++)
{
int+=multiple(message.charAt(i));
}
return width;
```

Comment: Pretty much the same as my solution, only using `switch` instead of a `HashMap`. `switch` internally uses a map of some sort, so it will be faster than `if-else`, dunno about the `HashMap`, perhaps too. `int` might not be granular enought, that's why I used double.

Comment: @MichałRus I thought of a hashmap, but I thought it would be kind of redundant as my understanding of a hashmap is that its mainly only faster in searching which in this case isn't an issue.

Answer (score 0):

First write a function that will take the width of i and a letter and returns the width of the letter.

```
int getWidth(int width_i, char ch){
  //TODO: write the logic and return the width
  return 0
}
```

In the main function:
1. Take the width of i from user
2. Take the input string for each character call getWidth(..) and add to the result.

```
int totalWidth(int width_i,String input){
  int sum=0;
  for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++){
    sum+=getWidth(width_i,input.charAt(i));
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: The same as @MikeBetterton's, almost the same as mine...